# WiX - VC++ Runtime - vcredist vs merge module

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, vcredist

I am building a MSI installer using WiX. As the product that is supposed to be installed requires a VC++ runtime I found the two option of doing that which are (a) using the corresponding merge module and (b) using burn to run vcredist prior to the actual product's MSI. To differ between those two options I have some questions I didn't find the information on.

1) If using the merge module the runtime is not installed separately (no entry in add and remove programs) but as far as I understand just copies the required files to their corresponding locations.

1.1) If there already is an installation of vcredist present on the system I suppose the merge module does nothing during the product's installation?

1.2) If there was a vcredist installation present as mentioned in 1.1) what happens if the user just uninstalls that runtime via add and remove programs? I suppose the product does not work anymore (at least until a repair installation is performed which causes the merge module stuff in the MSI to re-add the necessary files?)

1.3) If the vcredist was not yet installed and the MSI installer copies the files to the system and after that another installer or the user is calling the vcredist.exe what is happening then? Does vcredist reports the runtime as already being installed?

1.4) If uninstalling the product are the files copied to the system via the merge module being removed?

1.5) If the answer to 1.4) yes (VC++ runtime files are removed): If there are two different products are installed on the system both using the same merge module internally and one of the two products is uninstalled what happens to the installed runtime files? Are they removed and the other product is not working anymore due to the missing runtime files?

Thanks in advance for your help and information.

Regards,
Gunnar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A merge module is just a consistent way to install (usually shared) files properly by including them in a build. As an analogy, the C++ compilers build .obj files that are combined into an exe, but you can no longer talk about an obj having a separate existence after the exe is built and running. It's the same with merge modules. Once they are in the MSI they are just files to install, and they follow the standard rules. If a file is already installed (in the shared location) it will be overwritten if the incoming version is higher than the already installed version. Its containing component will be ref counted up by one, and uninstalling other products (including the VC redist) using the component will ref count down so that any products using the file don't break - there is still a version for them to use.This is just the standard sharing method for files shared amongst products, and it makes no difference that one product is a VC redist and the other is your MSI. It could just as easily be several of your products that each install the files using merge modules and each can be uninstalled without breaking the others because of the ref counting and that fact that the shared location and common component ID makes the sharing work as intended. So forget that one product is the VC redist and the other is yours (or another that uses the same files) - it's all just the Windows Installer's shared file/ref counting mechanism.

This is for the recent merge modules that install the files to the system folder. There have been other schemes using WinSxS and policy redirects that don't seem to be used now (VS 2015).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was just a little confused regarding merge module usage as I found several posts and description which prefer and recommend using Burn with vcredist.exe and the product installed by chaining those over merge module usage without giving comprehensible reason why not to use merge modules. As the bootstrapper always creates exe files instead of msi files (the latter is the preferred way of distributing installers in my company) I was wondering if there is any necessity to actually prefer vcredist.exe chaining instead of the MM, which doesn't seem to be the case.